# insertion failure in mongodb could

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

In this code, there is something which I can not find. Can you please help to solve this problem?

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://zenithjhony:*******@nodecoursa-iyyso.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology:true });
const dbname='conFusion';
client.connect(err => {
  //const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  console.log('connected to the server');
  const db=client.db(dbname);
  const collection=db.collection('dishes');
  collection.insertOne({"name":"Jhony","Description":"Test"},(err,result)=>{
      //assert.equal(err,null);
      console.log("After Insert: ");
  });
  client.close();
});
```

Not getting any error. But there is no data saved in my database

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting an error? You aren't doing anything with the `err` argument in `client.connect`, so it's possible that the callback is triggering *on error*. The callbacks are expected to handle the errors, so they aren't thrown. Also, your screenshot includes your credentials -- you definitely shouldn't be sharing those!

Comment: OK, @bscotchAdam it's a demo testing. But why I can not save information in my database?

Comment: The first thing you need to find out is if you are successfully connecting to your database. Try adding `console.log(err)` on the line right after `client.connect(err=>{` and check your logs to see if there is an error being thrown during connection. Currently you aren't checking to see if `err` is set to anything (things are only okay if `err` is `null`), so it's possible that you aren't even connected to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology:true });
```

With

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```